# Why I cannot play sound in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, audio

I have input all the sound (wav file) but i cannot load the sound when i run the project, only peep sound loaded.I have checked all my sound is in the res file.
PLEASE HELP

here is my code:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SoundPool sp;
private int c;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp = new SoundPool(2, 
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,5);
    c = sp.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.c,1);

}

public void playsound1 (View v) {
    sp.play(c,1.0F,1.0F,0,0,1.0F);

}
}
```

and the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/c_button"/>
```

there are more button is below....